# Problem in access or change value of a main thread from inside other thread in pyqt5

Tags: multithreading, qt, pyqt5, locking, mutex

I have a GUI that receive data from socket server, in main thread i have a variable start_capture, and in function process_feed change value of start_capture and also in another thread show called update_pic,show data, but i cant use correct way of mutex or lock:

```
class Test(QObject):
      def __init__(self):
          super().__init__()
          self.start_capture = False
          t1 = Thread(target=self.process_feed)
          t2 = Thread(target=self.update_pic)
          t1.start()
          t2.start()
      def process_feed(self):
          while True:
                if handler_is_pressed:
                   self.start_capture = True
                else:
                   self.start_capture = False
      def update_pic(self):
          while True:
                if self.start_capture:
                   ## show data in plot
```

i used Signal and Slot but when i run the app and send data, program got stupid and not work correctly.

Comment: Use QThreads instead of python threads, and send signals to communicate with main GUI.